# Save and Load PDF in my App

Tags: swift, pdf

I am downloading a .PDF file from a URL into a webview. It works fine , but because the pdf get updated mid month. I would like to download that file on the first of every month into my app, then the rest of the month load that saved file from the app rather than the web. Thank you for any help. I am using Swift.
following is my code so far :

```
import UIKit
import Social





// var justOnceThree:Bool = true

class KeyPagesViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var photoButton: UIButton!

@IBOutlet weak var baseKeypagesLabel: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var keyPages: UIWebView!

var urlFra = "http://someURL.pdf"
var urlLhr = "http://someURL.pdf"

let requestURL = NSURL()


override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

    PhotoButton()

}

override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    animationtitle()

    let sharedDefaults = NSUserDefaults(suiteName: "group.birkyboy.TodayExtensionSharingDefaults")
    var based = sharedDefaults!.objectForKey("base") as? String

    if based == "HNL" {
        let requestURL = NSURL(string:self.urlHnl)
        let request = NSURLRequest(URL: requestURL!)
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = true
        self.keyPages.hidden = false
        self.keyPages.loadRequest(request)
        self.baseKeypagesLabel.text = "HONOLULU"
    }

    if based == "IAH" {
        let requestURL = NSURL(string:self.urlIah)
        let request = NSURLRequest(URL: requestURL!)
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = true
        self.keyPages.hidden = false
        self.keyPages.loadRequest(request)
        self.baseKeypagesLabel.text = "HOUSTON"
    }
   }
```

Comment: This isn't a *"code my app for free site"*, what is your question?

Comment: Was not my intent to have someone to code for me. I just have no idea where to begin. my question was how can i save a PDF from url into the App for off line viewing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save the PDF in the users Documents folder. See "iOS Standard Directories: Where Files Reside" in the Apple documentation. There are various ways to get the PDF from a URL. See `NSInputStream` for one way to do it. Once you have it (as an `NSData` object, for example), you can save it as a file.

Comment: Interresting , I will document myself. Thank you for giving me directions.